# Not able to install Win Xp on Lenovo Ideapad z570

Tags: windows, installation

I want to install Win Xp on my Ideapad Z 570 laptop but i always get blue screen with message with some drive related problem which asks me to run CHKDSK command. I tried with that but no luck. Is there any way i can install Win Xp with SP 2 ?

Edit: i searched across the sites and came to know there could be some Compatibility problems, and i could fix it by setting HDD mode to IDE; will it solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, setting the HDD to IDE will probably fix the problem.  You can do this in the BIOS screen before boot.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep the functionality of AHCI (SATA) do not set it to IDE in the bios, instead use driver packs to slipstream "Mass Storage" drivers into the XP CD.

Driver packs tutorial, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

Download software "Driverpacks Base"

http://driverpacks.net/downloads

You can install other driver packs besides the "Mass Storage", but this will bloat the size of the XP install to DVD size, The only driver packs I suggest to slipstream are

Mass Storage, Chipset, Lan, CPU

This will keep it a size to fit on a CD. If you want all the drivers slipstreamed it will require a DVD burner to make the DVD and a DVD drive on the target installation PC.

I don't change any of the default settings when using the software, just pick the driver packs you want to slipstream, once they are slipped create the ISO image.

If you use other customizing software for other reasons than drivers such as Nlite, use Nlite first then driver packs last or install problems will result. Only use DP to slip drivers, do not use Nlite for this task.

Start with clean unmodified XP Installation files when using DP for best results

Note, Driverpacks no longer allows you to download the driverpacks from their site using the program (you will get an error), driverpacks are now distributed via bittorrent, the torrent file for each driverpack can be found on the driverpacks download page, or sign up on this forum and you can download driver packs directly. http://reboot.pro/forum/88/ Be sure to get the proper x86 version of the driver pack for XP.

once you have the 7zip Driverpack files you need, copy them (do not unzip them) into the "DriverPacks" folder where you installed the Base program. When you run the program skip the update driverpacks step in the process.